# Does all Object refers to same Prototype Object on top of prototype chain in javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypejs, prototype-chain

I run following code and it looks like ultimately all objects have same object prototype on top of prototype chain and then this prototype point to null as its own prototype. does it concludes that all the object refers to the same object prototype on top of prototype chain just like every objects in java inherits from Object Class?

```
const a = 10;
const b = {}
const c = new Object();

const fun = function () {return 'i am fun()';}

console.log(a.__proto__.__proto__ === b.__proto__); // true
console.log(b.__proto__ === c.__proto__); // true
console.log(fun.prototype.__proto__ === c.__proto__); // true
```

Comment: No: `Object.create(null)` wouldn't do this.

Comment: Okey, but excepts this case does questions answer is yes?

Comment: If you're asking "Is the top level object in the prototype chain Object.prototype, if we ignore when it isn't" then the answer is yes. However, if follows from the definition of the question.

Comment: Does Object.create(null) is used in real world softwares? I mean Can you please tell me when it's used. I am beginner in software development.

Comment: It's used when you want to make an object without a prototype. It's useful as a "property bag" as it won't have any extra properties leaking in from the prototype, like `toString`, `hasOwnProperty`, etc. Post ES6 we have the Map class that can handle this but lots of libraries pre-ES6 might use a plain object as a dictionary/map. Some code still uses it post-ES6 for variety of reasons. Just plain preference, or actual tangible benefit it might have over a map for a specific use-case.